# practical workaround of static_assert(false); in else constexpr{}

Tags: c++, c++17, static-assert, if-constexpr

How to easily `static_assert(false)` in `else{}` of `if constexpr`?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
class B{};
class C{};
class D{};
template<class T> void complexIf(){
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,B>){
        //^ actually it is some complex statement
        std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
    }else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,C>){
        //^ another uber complex thingy
        std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;
    }
    //another 4-5 "else if constexpr(){}"
    else{//#1
        static_assert(false);
    }
};
int main(){
    complexIf<B>();//  should compliable
    //complexIf<D>()   should uncompliable
}
```

The above MCVE isn't compilable.
The reason was explained in [constexpr if and static_assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304847/constexpr-if-and-static-assert/38316977#comment96752188_38316977)  .
( That question is more of a language-lawyer one. )

In this question, I would like to know an elegant workaround.

### My poor solutions

[The first workaround](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd0517234fbac591) (copy-paste condition to `#1`) :-

```
    else{//#1
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<T,B> &&std::is_same_v<T,C> );
        //^ a ton of copy-paste condition 
    }
```

^ It is less maintainable + dirty.

[My second attempt](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cefc136e50c00967) (cache as `constexpr bool`):-

```
template<class T> void complexIf(){
    constexpr bool case1=std::is_same_v<T,B>;
    constexpr bool case2=std::is_same_v<T,C>;
    if constexpr(case1){
        //^ actually it is some complex statement
        std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
    }else if constexpr(case2){
        //^ another uber complex thingy
        std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;
    }
    //another 4-5 "else if constexpr(){}"
    else{//#1
        static_assert(case1&case2 );
    }
}
```

^ It is less clear and quite confusing.

In real world, `complexIf` is a function to manage custom smart pointers.
Each `if constexpr` is mostly about checking type of the pointers.

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/29470096/4944425 (the `always_false<T>` part).

Comment: @StoryTeller Strange, my question is marked as duplicated by you at god speed, but my heart is so cheerful.  It works.  Thank!

Comment: Not that fast, though. It wasn't too easy to find. I hope your question may serve as a good sign pointing at it. I suspect it will help searches to come