# Why does gcc8.3 appear to attempt to compile an unused template function?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc8

Consider (the name of the file is hello.cpp) this code; the idea is to engineer a safe casting of numeric types without loss or overflow. (I'm porting some code from MSVC to g++).

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<
    typename T/*the desired type*/,
    typename/*the source type*/ Y
> T integral_cast(const Y& y)
{
    static_assert(false, "undefined integral cast");
}

// Specialisation to convert std::uint32_t to double
template<>
inline double integral_cast(const std::uint32_t& y)
{
    double ret = static_cast<double>(y);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::uint32_t a = 20;
    double f = integral_cast<double>(a); // uses the specialisation
    std::cout << f;
}
```

When I compile with gcc 8.3 by typing `g++ -o hello hello.cpp` I get the error `error: static assertion failed: undefined integral cast`.

This means that g++ is always compiling the unused template code.

Note that MSVC compiles this (which is nice since it allows me to spot any integral cast specialisations that I haven't considered).

Clearly I'm missing something. But what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional compilation of templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468724/conditional-compilation-of-templates): "The standard permits, but does not require, compilers to diagnose templates for which no valid instantiation can be generated."

Comment: @RaymondChen: The answer answers it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC isn't really "instantiating" or "compiling" the base function template. If it was, you would have two compiled functions with the same name and parameter list. As @Raymond Chen pointed out in the comments, GCC is permitted, but not required, to raise an error for templates that don't have any valid instantiation.

For example:

```
template<
    typename T/*the desired type*/,
    typename/*the source type*/ Y
> T integral_cast(const Y& y)
{
        static_assert(sizeof(Y) == 1);
};
```

Won't raise an error in the example you give (because it has a valid instantiation and is not instantiated).

I suspect GCC just needs to substitute the types into the base template for overload resolution, so it really just needs the *declaration*, not the *definition*.

You can get the behavior you want by using a deleted definition:

```
template<
    typename T/*the desired type*/,
    typename/*the source type*/ Y
> T integral_cast(const Y& y) = delete;
```

Comment: The deleted definition works really well - and the output diagnostic gives you the types, in both MSVC and g++. Thank you very much.